# Расчёт среднего кол-ва обработанных команд за определённый период времени

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочется понять какое среднее кол-во обработанных команд за определенный период происходит, а именно за 1 секунду / 1 минуту / 1 час / 24ч

У нас есть список из timestamps когда пришла каждая команда. `command_times = [time.time() - i for i in range(100)]` Требуется из этого списка произвести расчёт. Я попытался сделать функцию которая ниже. Но выдаёт какую то белеберду.

```
def calculate_commands_per_time(commands_timestamps):
    commands_per_second = 0
    commands_per_minute = 0
    commands_per_day = 0

    if not commands_timestamps:
        return commands_per_second, commands_per_minute, commands_per_day

    current_time = time.time()
    time_diff = current_time - commands_timestamps[0]

    # Рассчитываем количество команд в секунду
    if time_diff > 0:
        commands_per_second = len(commands_timestamps) / time_diff

    # Рассчитываем количество команд в минуту
    if time_diff >= 60:
        commands_per_minute = len(commands_timestamps) / (time_diff / 60)

    # Рассчитываем количество команд в 24 часа
    if time_diff >= 86400:  # 86400 секунд в 24 часах
        commands_per_day = len(commands_timestamps) / (time_diff / 86400)

    return commands_per_second, commands_per_minute, commands_per_day
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В списке хранятся времена прихода команд.

Заводятся 4 индекса - суточный, часовой `ind_h`, минутный и секундный.

При запросе, допустим, на количество команд в последний час `ind_h` двигается вправо, пока не встаёт на время, отстоящее от текущего не более, чем на час

```
while (now - timelist[ind_h]) > one_hour: 
   ind_h += 1
```

Количество за этот час получается `(len(timelist) - ind_h)`